# QtCreator + gdb on Mac OS X Yosemite doesn't give me source level debug info

Tags: boost, qt-creator, lldb, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

Debugger shows me dissassembler code, while i am trying to step over the instructions of my program.
Using lldb under QtCreator.
Interesting thing is: debugging works fine, if i use it without QtCreator (via terminal)

Small projects seems to debug normally... So I've try to add peaces of my project gradually to small one.
I've found a peace of code, that resulting to crash:

```
QVector<myClass>::contains();
```

But if i try to make an empty project only with this realisation, problem disappeared.
I've lost about a week, trying to solve it.
Any ideas, what can go wrong?

EDIT: 
Well, QtCreator still using GDB instead of LLDB, that i refer it to...
Looks like bug

Comment: So the title of this should be "QtCreator + gdb on Mac OS X Yosemite doesn't give me source level debug info", right?  Looking at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html it seems like QVector<T>::contains() requires a reference to an object (returning true if the QVector contains that object).  I don't see how that source line made it past the compiler?

Comment: From help: QVector::contains() requires the value type to have an implementation of operator==()

bool MyClass::operator== (const MyClass &class) const {
    return (this->number == class.number);
}

So, it's implemented right i think...
I've found that there is no support of GDB in OS X since OS X 10.9 Maverics.
Then i've tried to use LLDB.
But QtCreator seems to ignore my settings:
[link](http://cs618430.vk.me/v618430025/224bd/WFvc31Y-CUs.jpg)

Comment: Sorry I don't know QtCreator or why it has problems working with lldb as a debugger.  An IDE needs to do some work to support lldb in addition to gdb and I don't know if QtCreator has done that work.  I wouldn't be surprised if QtCreator could only work with gdb.

Comment: Yep. But now it's a question not about supporting debbugers by QtCreator. Right now it's question about QtCreator IDE itself. Changing options within it doesn't work as it should on Mac OS X. So at the moment i decided to install WinXP emulation and work with QtCreator + GDB. Thanks for paying attention.